# Slow query while searching a product woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

last days I am getting slow query (4+sec sql answer) while I try to search a product in admin dashboards search input.

Query monitor 4,782 sec (also execute the query direct in the mysql cli and I am getting the same time) wp_psotmeta table is "big" 200.000 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_parent as parent_id
    FROM wp_posts posts 
         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
    WHERE ( posts.post_title LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
            OR posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
            OR posts.post_content LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
            OR ( postmeta.meta_key = '_sku'
                 AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' ) ) 
          AND posts.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') 
    ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC
```

How can I reduce the respond time (without using cache)

```
+-------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                                            | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation              | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| wp_aryo_activity_log                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     26 |            630 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            143 | 2018-06-11 21:31:04 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_aws_cache                                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       49152 |               0 |            0 |   6291456 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:04 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_aws_index                                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 365747 |            104 |    38338560 |               0 |            0 |   7340032 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:05 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_commentmeta                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    101 |            162 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |            115 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_comments                                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    866 |            359 |      311296 |               0 |       294912 |         0 |            975 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_layerslider                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_layerslider_revisions                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_links                                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_masterslider_options                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              2 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_masterslider_sliders                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              2 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_newsletter                                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      5 |           3276 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              6 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_newsletter_emails                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_newsletter_sent                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_newsletter_stats                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_newsletter_user_logs                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_omega_sync_status                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      9 |           1820 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_options                                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   7556 |            873 |     6602752 |               0 |      1507328 |   4194304 |         409398 | 2018-06-11 21:31:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_piraeus_bank_transactions                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      9 |           1820 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |             10 | 2018-06-11 21:31:13 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_piraeusbank_transactions                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    153 |            107 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            188 | 2018-06-11 21:31:13 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_postmeta                                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 212550 |            175 |    37306368 |               0 |     24215552 |   4194304 |         245092 | 2018-06-11 21:31:13 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_posts                                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  17042 |           1016 |    17317888 |               0 |      4128768 |   4194304 |          25216 | 2018-06-11 21:31:20 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_css                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    109 |           1202 |      131072 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            110 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_layer_animations                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_navigations                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              2 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_sliders                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      2 |          24576 |       49152 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              3 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_slides                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      6 |          57344 |      344064 |               0 |            0 |         0 |             22 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_revslider_static_slides                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_slp_extendo_meta                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_store_locator                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_term_relationships                           | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  32541 |             48 |     1589248 |               0 |      1589248 |   4194304 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_term_taxonomy                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   2862 |             85 |      245760 |               0 |       294912 |         0 |           3120 | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_termmeta                                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   3510 |             70 |      245760 |               0 |       376832 |         0 |           3756 | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_terms                                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   2862 |             85 |      245760 |               0 |       278528 |         0 |           3120 | 2018-06-11 21:31:23 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_usermeta                                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   2380 |             96 |      229376 |               0 |       245760 |         0 |           4391 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_users                                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     56 |            292 |       16384 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |             59 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wc_download_log                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wc_webhooks                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_api_keys                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    181 |            271 |       49152 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |            197 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_log                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   6854 |             69 |      475136 |               0 |       442368 |         0 |           9572 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_order_items                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   1037 |             94 |       98304 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |           1478 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_sessions                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   4842 |           5755 |    27869184 |               0 |       491520 |   5242880 |         105968 | 2018-06-11 21:31:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_shipping_table_rates             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    774 |            127 |       98304 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            781 | 2018-06-11 21:31:26 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations          | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   1317 |             74 |       98304 |               0 |       147456 |         0 |           3500 | 2018-06-11 21:31:26 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    195 |             84 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            207 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones                   | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     67 |            244 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |             71 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woocommerce_tax_rates                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      2 |           8192 |       16384 |               0 |        65536 |         0 |              4 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woof_query_cache                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woof_stat_buffer                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_woof_stat_tmp                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci     |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza                                       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      3 |           5461 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              5 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_categories                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_category_maps                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_circles                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_maps                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              2 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_polygon                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_polylines                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_wpgmza_rectangles                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci        |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_yoast_seo_links                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     99 |            165 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |            995 | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| wp_yoast_seo_meta                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   2089 |             54 |      114688 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-06-11 21:31:27 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Mysql Explain command

```
+------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | posts    | ALL  | type_status_date | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 17042 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | postmeta | ref  | post_id          | post_id | 8       | theodoulidis.posts.ID |     8 | Using where; Distinct                        |
+------+-------------+----------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please run the query using EXPLAIN keyword before and post it's output, most likely it is not using the proper index or an index is missing.
Apart from that LIKE queries are pretty costly.

Comment: explain says key null, i am copying it here

Comment: When you use a query with 'like' it's more expensive than equal. The 'or' is expensive too. It may be a good idea to go for a fulltext index. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629491/mysql-full-text-search-vs-like

Answer (score 3):

Too many things in the way of optimizing

```
WHERE ( posts.post_title LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
        OR posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
        OR posts.post_content LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' 
        OR ( postmeta.meta_key = '_sku'
             AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%' ) ) 
      AND posts.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') 
ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC
```

Index(es) are needed, *but*...

- `OR` inhibits the use of indexes.
- `OR` between two tables makes it even worse.
- `LIKE` with leading wildcard inhibits use of indexes.
- `IN (x, y)` (multiple options) prevents using that together with the `ORDER BY`.
- `UNION` in place of `OR` would be far to messy without some of the other things to be 'fixed'.
- A `FULLTEXT` index can work across multiple columns, but only within a single table.
- But is `"INVMCB278A2W"` technically a "word"?
- There are [ways to speed up postmeta](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) but other issues prevent getting to them.

Tackle what you can of the tips here and other have given you, then come back and see if it is close enough for us to help finish the task.

Comment: Yes is the code name of a the product
wordpress return just one row ( the product INVMCB278A2W )

also before 1-2 weeks it "was" faster now it stall 4-5 secs

Comment: @JohnPapadopoulos - "was faster..." -- How much RAM do you have?  How big (GB) is the entire dataset?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: 16GB ram, the database is 75 MB, post table 17MB postmeta 32MB (table status) innodb although i run redis (of course the second time is fastest but the thing is. Its an Admin search so most of the time is only one time search and always user "see" 5sec delay.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and no amount of indexes or optimisation helped (63,000 products).

I took the query apart and found that it was the SKU search that was slowing things down.

After hours of digging into Woocommerce's code i finally found where the query is formed and removed the SKU search.

To do this yourself edit **/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php** file, look for the **search_products** function and remove the SKU search from the line starting **"$term_group_query .="** (line 1397 in WC version 3.4.4)

If you want you can also remove the join onto the wp_postmeta entirely a little bit further down on line 1423.

Obviously this isn't a suitable solution if you want to actually search the SKUs.

Comment: I was getting closer and closer by drilling down the code, but found your answer and tried the SQL query right away and... for sure it was the SKUs! I posted my own answer with code to show how I solved it by intercepting the query with a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create indexes on the related columns of your tables, such as;

```
ID, post_title, post_parent in wp_posts table,
post_id, wp_postmeta table
```

Also put indexes for varchar fields and ***rewrite your where criteria not having a wildchard (%) on the left side***. For example:

```
posts.post_title LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%'
```

will not use the index on column post_title
but

```
posts.post_title LIKE 'INVMCB278A2W%'
```

will use index

Comment: But...  `OR` prevents the use of those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very niche problem that our team just faced on a simple WooCommerce that started to have a good amount of products (1k+). Just like @CrashM mentioned, the problem lies within the SKU part of the SQL query found in class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php in the "search_products" function, around line 1687.

The optimal solution is to simply override the function thanks to the filter that can be found earlier within the same function. The filter is called "woocommerce_product_pre_search_products" and returning product ids will bypass the rest of the function altogether, so you can implement a simpler query by replicating part of the function or even your own, cache the results, etc.

Below is what I came up with to solve our problem quickly since we don't need to search by any meta field at any time except sometimes by SKU, so I added a little bit of sugar to re-allow searching by SKU by kicking in a different MySQL query if the search term starts by "sku:" or "SKU:".

I haven't added a general "is_admin" check because our problem was happening in the frontend as well and the filter kicks in there too, but if the admin's filterable dropdowns are the only problem for you, you can add a "is_admin" condition around the whole code to avoid it interfering with product search plugins, etc.

```php
/**
 * Solves the post_meta bottleneck caused by SKU and other metas being included uselessly while searching products
 * Mostly replicates the code in search_products at class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:1585 and adds a condition
 * to re-allow searching by sku if the search query starts with "SKU:" or "sku:"
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_pre_search_products', function($unused, $term, $type = '', $include_variations = false, $all_statuses = false, $limit = null) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_types   = $include_variations ? array( 'product', 'product_variation' ) : array( 'product' );
    $status_where = '';
    $limit_query  = '';
    /**
     * Hook woocommerce_search_products_post_statuses.
     *
     * @since 3.7.0
     * @param array $post_statuses List of post statuses.
     */
    $post_statuses = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_search_products_post_statuses',
        current_user_can( 'edit_private_products' ) ? array( 'private', 'publish' ) : array( 'publish' )
    );

    if ( ! $all_statuses ) {
        $status_where = " AND posts.post_status IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_statuses ) . "') ";
    }

    if ( $limit ) {
        $limit_query = $wpdb->prepare( ' LIMIT %d ', $limit );
    }

    /**
     * Check if search starts with "SKU:" or "sku:"
     */
    $start_check_sku = strtoupper(substr($term, 0, 4));
    if($start_check_sku === 'SKU:') {
        $search_term = substr($term, 4);
        $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%';
        $skusearch = $wpdb->prepare( " AND wc_product_meta_lookup.sku LIKE %s ", $like );
        $search_results = $wpdb->get_results(
            // phpcs:disable
            "SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} wc_product_meta_lookup ON posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id
            WHERE posts.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "')
            $skusearch
            $status_where
            $limit_query
            "
            // phpcs:enable
        );
        $product_ids = wp_list_pluck($search_results, 'product_id');
    }else {

        // See if search term contains OR keywords.
        if ( stristr( $term, ' or ' ) ) {
            $term_groups = preg_split( '/\s+or\s+/i', $term );
        } else {
            $term_groups = array( $term );
        }

        $search_where   = '';
        $search_queries = array();

        foreach ( $term_groups as $term_group ) {
            // Parse search terms.
            if ( preg_match_all( '/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\t ",+])|^)[^\t ",+]+/', $term_group, $matches ) ) {
                // $search_terms = $this->get_valid_search_terms( $matches[0] );
                $search_terms = array();
                $stopwords = apply_filters( 'wp_search_stopwords', array_map(
                    'wc_strtolower',
                    array_map(
                        'trim',
                        explode(
                            ',',
                            _x(
                                'about,an,are,as,at,be,by,com,for,from,how,in,is,it,of,on,or,that,the,this,to,was,what,when,where,who,will,with,www',
                                'Comma-separated list of search stopwords in your language',
                                'woocommerce'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ));

                foreach ( $matches[0] as $term ) {
                    // keep before/after spaces when term is for exact match, otherwise trim quotes and spaces.
                    if ( preg_match( '/^".+"$/', $term ) ) {
                        $term = trim( $term, "\"'" );
                    } else {
                        $term = trim( $term, "\"' " );
                    }

                    // Avoid single A-Z and single dashes.
                    if ( empty( $term ) || ( 1 === strlen( $term ) && preg_match( '/^[a-z\-]$/i', $term ) ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ( in_array( wc_strtolower( $term ), $stopwords, true ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $search_terms[] = $term;
                }
                $count        = count( $search_terms );

                // if the search string has only short terms or stopwords, or is 10+ terms long, match it as sentence.
                if ( 9 < $count || 0 === $count ) {
                    $search_terms = array( $term_group );
                }
            } else {
                $search_terms = array( $term_group );
            }

            $term_group_query = '';
            $searchand        = '';

            foreach ( $search_terms as $search_term ) {
                $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%';
                $term_group_query .= $wpdb->prepare( " {$searchand} ( ( posts.post_title LIKE %s) )", $like, $like, $like ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.InterpolatedNotPrepared
                $searchand         = ' AND ';
            }

            if ( $term_group_query ) {
                $search_queries[] = $term_group_query;
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $search_queries ) ) {
            $search_where = ' AND (' . implode( ') OR (', $search_queries ) . ') ';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $include ) && is_array( $include ) ) {
            $search_where .= ' AND posts.ID IN(' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $include ) ) . ') ';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $exclude ) && is_array( $exclude ) ) {
            $search_where .= ' AND posts.ID NOT IN(' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $exclude ) ) . ') ';
        }

        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.VIP.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
        $search_results = $wpdb->get_results(
            // phpcs:disable
            "SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_title as post_title, posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts
            WHERE posts.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "')
            $search_where
            $status_where
            ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC
            $limit_query
            "
            // phpcs:enable
        );

        $product_ids = wp_parse_id_list( array_merge( wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'product_id' ), wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'parent_id' ) ) );

        if ( is_numeric( $term ) ) {
            $post_id   = absint( $term );
            $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

            if ( 'product_variation' === $post_type && $include_variations ) {
                $product_ids[] = $post_id;
            } elseif ( 'product' === $post_type ) {
                $product_ids[] = $post_id;
            }

            $product_ids[] = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_id );
        }
    }

    return wp_parse_id_list( $product_ids );
}, 10, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

the indexes to add:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ADD INDEX `wp_postmeta_idx_key_id_value` (`meta_key`,`post_id`,`meta_value`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `wp_posts_idx_type_parent_title_id` (`post_type`,`post_parent`,`post_title`,`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `wp_posts_idx_content_parent_title_id` (`post_content`,`post_parent`,`post_title`,`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `wp_posts_idx_excerpt_parent_title_id` (`post_excerpt`,`post_parent`,`post_title`,`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `wp_posts_idx_title_parent_id` (`post_title`,`post_parent`,`ID`);
```

The query to execute:

```
SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        ((SELECT
            posts.ID AS product_id,
            posts.post_parent AS parent_id,
            posts.post_title 
        FROM
            wp_posts posts 
        WHERE
            (
                (
                    1 = 1 
                    AND 1 = 1
                )
            ) 
            AND posts.post_type IN (
                'product', 'product_variation'
            ) 
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    * 
                FROM
                    wp_postmeta postmeta 
                WHERE
                    posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
                    AND postmeta.meta_key = '_sku' 
                    AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%'
            ) 
        ORDER BY
            posts.post_parent ASC,
            posts.post_title ASC) 
        UNION
        DISTINCT (SELECT
            DISTINCT posts.ID AS product_id,
            posts.post_parent AS parent_id,
            posts.post_title 
        FROM
            wp_posts posts 
        WHERE
            (posts.post_content LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%') 
            AND posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
        ORDER BY
            posts.post_parent ASC,
            posts.post_title ASC) 
    UNION
    DISTINCT (SELECT
        DISTINCT posts.ID AS product_id,
        posts.post_parent AS parent_id,
        posts.post_title 
    FROM
        wp_posts posts 
    WHERE
        (posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%') 
        AND posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
    ORDER BY
        posts.post_parent ASC,
        posts.post_title ASC) 
UNION
DISTINCT (SELECT
    DISTINCT posts.ID AS product_id,
    posts.post_parent AS parent_id,
    posts.post_title 
FROM
    wp_posts posts 
WHERE
    (posts.post_title LIKE '%INVMCB278A2W%') 
    AND posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
ORDER BY
    posts.post_parent ASC,
    posts.post_title ASC)
) AS union1 
ORDER BY
union1.post_parent ASC,
union1.post_title ASC
```